# jquery slideshow doesn't appears while site loading.only appears when the site refresh again

Tags: jquery, slideshow

i included a slideshow..it works properly
but it doesn't appears first time when site loading.while we refresh the page again the slideshow appears..

```
code is

<script src="js/jquery.1.3.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jqFancyTransitions.1.8.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.bxSlider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="slideshowHolder">
<img alt="" src="images/100.JPG" /><img alt="" src="images/101.JPG" />
<img alt="" src="images/102.JPG" /><img alt="" src="images/103.JPG" />
<img alt="" src="images/104.JPG" /><img alt="" src="images/105.JPG" />
<img alt="" src="images/106.JPG" /><img alt="" src="images/107.JPG" />
<img alt="" src="images/108.JPG" /><img alt="" src="images/109.JPG" />
</div>
<script>

$('#slideshowHolder').bxSlider({

            speed: 700,

            pause: 4000,                   

            auto: true,

            infiniteLoop: false 

        });

</script>
```

i included all js files..slideshow doesn't appers when site loading..only after the page refresh again.Any idea???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try nesting your JS code in

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //....
});
```

As it is, the images aren't available to the JS at the time of execution.

Comment: where can i post this code? before $('#slideshowHolder').bxSlider({  ?

Comment: NEST your code in this code.  ie.  put your code INSIDE this code (replace //.... with your code)